# how to create application for Android tablet (Honeycomb 3.2 Api13)

Tags: java, android

```
hii i am new in android i have create application for android 2.2  api (8)  .
```

i want to develop application for android tab But not how i start even i m not able to parse

```
http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/Services.aspx?service=getStatutesTabNews
```

please tell me how i build application for android tab.

```
please post me some link of Honey comb example with parsing and Ui Design .
```

Comment: Please, someone tell me what he wants..

Comment: how create application for android Tab do u have any dummy Example for Honey comb can u post link for that

Comment: Please specify your question......

Comment: like the same way you did for 2.2 just see that your manifest sets min SDk version as 13 or what ever you want.Plus for new features eg. ActionBar you can visit developers site .it has many examples.